# django model objects...why do I NOT have to create an object?

Tags: django

I have noticed with model objects in django that I can do:

```
MyModel.objects.all()
```

I can do this without making a new MyModel object. How/why does this work?

Edited the question:
I am not asking about the base Model class, but I am talking about a model called MyModel that extends from the base Model class

Comment: Without any objects, `all` returns an empty queryset. What did you expect?

Comment: Yes but there's no db table for `Model` - I can understand the question - why's there no error thrown (Chris isn't doing `MyModel.objects.all()` he's querying the base model class)

Comment: No he is not: `AttributeError: type object 'Model' has no attribute 'objects'`.

Comment: Think you need to edit your question Chris.

Comment: I have edited question to be more specific

Answer (score 5):

### What is Model.objects

Model classes, have a [Manager class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/), you can get it like this:

```
YourModel.objects
```

The Manager is the one making SQL queries, for example, this will return a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/):

```
YourModel.objects.all()
```

A [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) behaves mostly like a normal python list, except that it will make an SQL query when it is first [evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

### The base model class has no manager !

So you cannot do `Model.objects.all()` as you said:

```
In [1]: from django.db.models import Model

In [2]: Model.objects
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/jpic/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.pyc in <module>()
----> 1 Model.objects

AttributeError: type object 'Model' has no attribute 'objects'
```

### A QuerySet will fail if the table doesn't exist !

It will throw a DatabaseError:

```
     50     def execute(self, query, args=None):
     51         try:
---> 52             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
     53         except Database.IntegrityError, e:
     54             raise utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e)), sys.exc_info()[2]

DatabaseError: relation "formapp_testmodel" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "formapp_testmodel"."id" FROM "formapp_testmodel" LIM...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define a model `class MyModel(models.Model)` and then run `python manage.py syncdb`, django will create a databse table `yourapp_mymodel`. You can run queries against that db table that return no tuples, so you can create a queryset that contains no results - eg `MyModel.objects.none()`.

The queryset api would be pretty hopeless if it threw an exception every time you ran a query that returned no results.

(I've assumed that you meant to ask why you can do `MyModel.objects.all()` rather than `Model.objects.all()`. As jpic shows in his answer you can't do `Model.objects.all()`.